# How to get a value other than a boolean in a predicate?

Tags: functional-programming, conditional-statements, scheme, racket

I am trying to add an element into a list if it is  zero as part of a recursive function that removes all non-zeroes from a list. if it is non-zero then I just want the code to continue on. Here's what I have so far:

```
(cons 
   (cond [(zero? (first list_of_numbers)) 
          (first list_of_numbers)]) 
   (continue the recursive function))
```

However, I get the following error:

> ```
> cond: all question results were false
> ```

Comment: Pick one: "removes all non-zeroes from a list" or "only non-zero numbers are added to the list"

Comment: Have changed it. Apologies for the contradictions

Comment: And should that function also work for nested lists? (for example, `(list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) (list 0 1 0))`)

Comment: No. I have added a test case

Answer (score 2):

You're asked to write a recursive function, so you should start with the terminating condition/ base case:

```
(define (keep-zeros lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) '())
```

In the next `cond` branch, you will use your condition ([`zero?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._zero%7E3f%29%29)) and if `(first lst)` passes, you will `cons` it to the result of  `(keep-zeros (rest lst))`:

```
        ((zero? (first lst))
         (cons (first lst)
               (keep-zeros (rest lst))))
```

Final `cond` branch- if that number is non-zero, you will just drop it and call your function on the rest of list:

```
        (else (keep-zeros (rest lst)))))
```

All together:

```
(define (keep-zeros lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) '())
        ((zero? (first lst))
         (cons (first lst)
               (keep-zeros (rest lst))))
        (else (keep-zeros (rest lst)))))
```

Test:

```
> (keep-zeros (cons 0 (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 0 empty)))))
(cons 0 (cons 0 '()))
```